# Can't access S/W upgrade mode

Tags: root-access, lg-optimus-4x

I have a LG 4x HD ( P880 ).

I have rooted it and tried to install a rom but the error : " invalid image signiature " turned up when trying to turn it on and it shuts down right after.

My idea was to reflush it, I plug in the power cord, take out the sim and the battery but when I open it up it doesn't go into the s/w upgrade mode. If I don't hold down any key it goes into a random-colored window and otherwise no matter what key I hold it turns blank black and nothing happens. I know it is supposed to go into the s/w mode by pressing vol - but that just sends it to the blank black screen.

I did reflush it before and it worked just fine, didn't had any problems getting into the S/W upgrade mode.

How can I gain access to it?